# Linux Utility for "Timestamping" Functionality

Tags: linux, command-line, timestamp, incremental-backup, command-line-tool

wget's [timestamping](http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/wget_5.html) functionality ensures it only downloads files that have changed. I'm looking for a linux command-line tool that will recursively compare a directories contents with a saved version (from the last time it ran), and execute an arbitary shell command on any new or updated files. Basically:

```
run-on-updated --directory /path/to/my/dir --last-results ~/.lastrun --exec "echo {}"
```

I could even imagine this as an extension of the 'find' command. Does such a tool exist?

Comment: ~/.lastrun is just a file, right? Not a copy of the complete directory? In the latter case you could start with `rsync -v --dry-run /path/to/my/dir ~/.lastrun`

Comment: Ideally it should be just the file metadata (e.g. path, size, last-modified) rather than a copy of the directory as that'd be too large. rsync definitely has this timestamping functionality though - but I hope to find it as a standalone tool (the unix philosophy?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attempt to answer the question -- probably with lots of room for improvement:

```
tar -cv -f /dev/null -g ~/.lastrun /path/to/my/dir | grep -ve '/$' | xargs -I{} echo '{}'
```

Note for the tar command: "The option ‘-g’ instructs tar to operate on an incremental archive with additional metadata stored in a standalone file, called a snapshot file. The purpose of this file is to help determine which files have been changed, added or deleted since the last backup, so that the next incremental backup will contain only modified files." (Quote from doc)

The `grep` command excludes directory names (ending with /) which tar always outputs, and finally `xargs`will run the desired command on the files.

Comment: This works! It updates the ~/.lastrun file in-place which is useful too.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Please take care if there are some file names with whitespaces (I was too tired yesterday to think of that ;) You'll be saver when using `xargs -I{} echo '{}'` -- I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by the sentence "compare a directories contents with a saved version", but to do what the answer of mpy does, I would prefer `find`:

Before running the `find` command the first time, you need to run the `touch` command do create the timestamp file:

```
touch .lastrun
```

Later, run the touch command after the find run:

```
find my/dir -type f -newer .lastrun -exec echo '{}' \;
touch .lastrun
```

The file `.lastrun` will never be listed itself, because it is never newer than itself.